# How to sart Adobe Air App with arguments?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, adobe, mxml

How to sart Adobe Air App with arguments, is it possible, at least with native apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[How do I use command line arguments with my AIR application?](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_do_I_use_command_line_arguments_with_my_AIR_ap-8003.html)**

> In AIR you can have your application
>   listen for an InvokeEvent. This event
>   will contain any arguments that were
>   passed into the application via the
>   command line both at launch and while
>   the application is running.